# Need a list of Android devices with specs

Tags: android

I am looking for a list of Android devices that has the following info (at least):

- Device Name
- User Agent String
- Screen Format (of the three supported Android screen sizes)
- Touch Enabled?
- Maximum HTML5 Database Size

There are some lists online (like the one on Wikipedia), but it does not have all of this data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you'll have to compile a list of this information yourself. [That list you mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices) is a great place to start. The problem is that there are so many manufacturers and so many different models, I don't know that anyone has bothered to catalog all of them with all of their particular specs in one easy-to-read place.

Finding the maximum HTML5 DB size for each device will probably be the most difficult thing. If you're looking for an upper bound on space usage, just go with the lowest you find.

If you do end up finding or compiling this list, be sure to post it here... there's a lot of Android devs who would be interested in seeing it.